# xml displaying incorrectly in ie10 with xsl file using transformNode()

Tags: xml, xslt, msxml, internet-explorer-10

I am getting my data displaying in Chineese type language in IE10 when doing the following:

```
      ICVID = Request.QueryString("ICVID")
      strXML = GetXML(ICVID) 'Gets data in xml format

Dim oDOM, xSS
Set oDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
oDOM.async = False
Set xSS = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xSS.async = False
oDOM.loadXML strXML
...
xSS.load Server.MapPath("GMTInboundCharges.xsl")
If xSS.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
    Response.Write xSS.parseError
End If
Response.Write oDOM.transformNode(xSS)
```

Works fine in previous versions of IE10.  I have seen other posts regarding the changes in IE10 with the xml response, but I am not using AJAX.  Wondering what changes I need to make to get my data to display correctly.
thanks.

Comment: That looks like server-side classic ASP code so it is not obvious why it would result in problems within a certain browser or a certain version of a certain browser. Can you explain in more detail what the problem is? I don't understand what "data displaying in Chineese[sic] type language" means exactly. What kind of output does the XSLT create, HTML, XML, plain text? Are you sending a proper Content-Type header with your server-side code to the browser/user agent? Are you sending a charset param to that Content-Type?

Comment: Yes, it is classic ASP code.  The problem is when the Response.Write statement is executed, it displays the xml data in, it looks like chineese.  Trying to get a screenshot...

Comment: @MartinHonnen - i guess I can't add screenshots.  But, the output literally looks like lines of chineese on the screen.  It's suppose to be the xml formated using the xsl file.  I'm not much of an xml programmer so I'm assuming that I'm not sending a Content-Type header.  Not sure where else to look for that.  the code that I posted was the jist of the modal code that displays the data, minus the GetXML function.

Comment: With IE 10, hit F12 and look at the network tab (after a reload), then check the Content-Type response header for the MIME type and any charset parameter.

Comment: I would also try to right click in the IE browser window and check and change the encoding to test whether that way the content is displayed as you want it. If that helps then know your ASP code needs to set the charset param on the Content-Type header.

Comment: The Content-Type is: Content-Type: text/html   Didn't see any charset parameters.  Found this in Fiddler.

Comment: This is the encoding that is in the .xsl file.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: Right click into the IE window and check which encoding is used to render the document then play with different encodings to see whether that way the rendering is as you want it. Once you have found a proper encoding use `Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=encodingNameGoesHere"` in your ASP code, before sending any contents to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 broke transformnode & reponseXML integration.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx#comments

(responseXML is no longer a MSXML Element you can .transformNode on)

I have not found any solutions yet.